# IframeExtractor don't output sound with rtsp

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg, codec

I use IframeExtractor from the git [mooncatventure](https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/iFrameExtractor), it play nice the .mov file. 
But when i try to read a rtsp stream, i hear no sound.

This is the FFMEG dump from the rtsp stream:

```
Metadata:
title           : unknown
comment         : unknown
Duration: N/A, start: 49435.000589, bitrate: 258 kb/s
Program 3223 
No Program
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1(fra): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 142 kb/s
Stream #0:2(fra): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
Stream #0:3(qad): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 47 kb/s
Stream #0:4(qaa): Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 68 kb/s
```

And this is the dump from the local .mov file that work:

```
Metadata:
major_brand     : qt  
minor_version   : 0
compatible_brands: qt  
creation_time   : 2010-01-17 21:52:33
model           : iPhone 3GS
model-eng       : iPhone 3GS
date            : 2010-01-17T16:52:33-0500
date-eng        : 2010-01-17T16:52:33-0500
encoder         : 3.1.2
encoder-eng     : 3.1.2
make            : Apple
make-eng        : Apple
Duration: 00:00:03.25, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3836 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 3695 kb/s, 30.02 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc
Metadata:
  rotate          : 90
  creation_time   : 2010-01-17 21:52:33
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 63 kb/s
Metadata:
  creation_time   : 2010-01-17 21:52:33
  handler_name    : Core Media Data Handler
```

The audio class that manage sounds contain a codec detector which say that the codec CODEC_ID_AAC is found for the two input:

```
audioStreamBasicDesc_.mFormatFlags = 0;
switch (_audioCodecContext->codec_id) {
    case CODEC_ID_MP3:
         audioStreamBasicDesc_.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3;
        break;
    case CODEC_ID_AAC:
         audioStreamBasicDesc_.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
         audioStreamBasicDesc_.mFormatFlags = kMPEG4Object_AAC_Main;
        NSLog(@"audio format aac %s (%d) is  supported",  _audioCodecContext->codec_name, _audioCodecContext->codec_id);
        break;
}
```

I see data going into the buffer but i hear nothing. It's maybe audioStreamBasicDesc_ which has wrong settings but i can't find what.

Is it possible that it's not the same AAC codec ?

Has someone experienced the same issue ?

Any help are welcome, i'm on this problem since some days now.

Edit:
I have found a error that i had not before, i don't know how to resolve it. If i change audioStreamBasicDesc.mFramesPerPacket to 0 or divided by 2, the error message dissapear.

```
AudioConverterNew returned 'fmt?'
Prime failed ('fmt?'); will stop (72000/0 frames)
```

Comment: Sure but that is a very simple audio decoder designed for mono camera input , there's a couple sample projects with more sophisticated audio decoders, see sample decoder, rtspplay etc. For anything more we have commercial offerings that will work, you may not have all the information needed calculate the buffer .

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing a buffer size here of some arbitraraly large size, say 480000

```
status = AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(audioQueue_, 
    audioStreamBasicDesc_.mSampleRate * kAudioBufferSeconds / 8, 
    _audioCodecContext->sample_rate * kAudioBufferSeconds / 
      _audioCodecContext->frame_size + 1, 
    &audioQueueBuffer_[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Michelle! Forcing the buffer size still don't output any sounds. Maybe the aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D) and aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F) description has something to do. I have error too in my log, i'll edit and add them in my original answer.

Comment: Just have tester your RtspPlay, it's a nice player but video and sound are not continuous With my rtsp url.

Comment: We don't get a lot of audio issues with that player, and your url didn't work with the iframeextractor which makes me think something else is going on here. Maybe packet loss, try putting ?tcp at the end of your url string, this should try to force using tcp rather than udp.

Comment: I have try to pass the tcp option but i think the rtsp server doesn't accept it. I get "method SETUP failed: 461 Unsupported Transport. Without tcp, i have a lot of "ac-tex damaged at...", "mb incr damaged", "00 motion_type at..", "slice mismatch". The url play fine in vlc.

Comment: Since they are on different platforms you can't make the assumption if it works in vlc and not iOS it must be the player, the issue is all those messages you are getting, so something is blocking udp , are you using your device on wifi or cellular. I'd love to try this on our commercial non sdl offering but you'd have to work directly with us for that

Comment: I use Wifi and have check my firewall (when i use simulator) and it's disabled. A wireshark sniff on my linux computer with this same url on vlc show me mostly UDP packets. In fact the link i use is a TVbox from my internet provider to watch TV on a real TV or on any device which is on my local network. I don't think i can change something on this box to make it work with TCP and i see it's working fine with VLC and UDP. It Would be nice if i could give you the link to test but your are not on my local network...

Comment: if you have ffmpeg installed on your linux box try running ffprobe and see what the output is. also a full ios log would help a lot. We probably could help you figure out what is going on, if you like you can join our facebook app dev group were we can live chat.